# Обновления сообщения Telegram API Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

```
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['weather'])
def send_weather(message: Message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите город, погода в котором, Вас интересует')
    city = types.Update.message
    URL = 'https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?city=' + city + '&lang=ru&key='
    weather = requests.get(URL)
    print(URL)
```

После bot.send_message(), мне нужно в city передать сообщение, которое написано в чат с ботом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сколько я понял вопрос, вам нужно в city передать, то что ввел пользователь в ответ на сообщение. Если да, то почитайте про next_step_handler https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py
а код примерно должен будет выглядеть так:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['weather'])
def send_weather(message: Message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите город, погода в котором, Вас интересует')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, print_city_url)

def print_city_url(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    city = message.text
    URL = 'https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?city=' + city + '&lang=ru&key='
    weather = requests.get(URL)
    print(URL)

bot.enable_save_next_step_handlers(delay = 2)

bot.polling()
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Такое обычно решается через FSM. Не уверен, есть ли у этой библиотеки такое. Советую ознакомиться с `aiogram`.

https://surik00.gitbooks.io/aiogram-lessons/content/chapter3.html