# Обновление переменной telebot

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Пишу ТГ бота, сразу говорю я новичок в программировании, и вот тут у меня заминка:

```
    elif message.text == 'Пожелания':
        try:
            file = open('predlojenie.txt')
        except FileNotFoundError:
            file = open('predlojenie.txt', 'x')
            file.close()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Напишите ваше пожелание:')
        message = message.text
        print(message)
        file = open('predlojenie.txt','a')
        file.write(message)
        file.close()
```

На выходе в файл записывается только сообщение, которое и должно было вызывать Функцию. То есть в файл записывается: **Пожелания**
Как рефрешнуть сообщение, чтобы при вводе в файл шло 2 сообщение а не 1?

Comment: А вообще библиотека telebot это вчерашний день
[Уроки по созданию бота](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wj1Vwq3IrL4&list=PLwVBSkoL97Q3phZRyInbM4lShvS1cBl-U)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Готовый код:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send(message):
    if message.text == 'Пожелания':
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напишите ваше пожелание:')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, save)

def save(message):
    try:
        with open('predlojenie.txt', 'r') as file:
            pass
    except FileNotFoundError:
        with open('predlojenie.txt', 'x') as file:
            pass
    print(message.text)
    with open('predlojenie.txt', mode='a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(message.text)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пожелание записано!')

bot.enable_save_next_step_handlers(delay = 2)
```

Шаблон взял из: [Обновления сообщения Telegram API Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1073761/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-telegram-api-python)